# SQL Server window function implementation issue

Tags: sql-server, row-number

I have a table structure like below:

[image]

I have the following query to get the unique result from the table:

```
 WITH Dupes AS 
 (
     SELECT    
         ID, Template_ID, Address, Job_Number, Other_Info,
         Assigned_By, Assignees, Active, seen,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Template_ID,Job_Number ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
     FROM 
         Schedule  
     WHERE 
         Assignees IN ('9', '16', '22')
)
SELECT 
    ID, Template_ID, Job_Number, Address, Other_Info,
    Assigned_By, Assignees, Active, seen 
FROM 
    Dupes 
WHERE 
    RowNum = 1
```

Output of the above query is:

[image]

If the Job_Number and Template_ID are same, only return one row(first row using ID). That is why I did use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Template_ID,Job_Number ORDER BY  ID) AS RowNum`. I am not sure how to fix this as I rarely used this function.

I need to get the output like below:

[image]

**Updated Code**

Tried the code below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems your trying to group by `Job_Number`, remove `Template_ID` on your `partition by` clause

```
 WITH Dupes AS 
 (
      SELECT  ID,Template_ID,Address,Job_Number,Other_Info,Assigned_By,Assignees,Active,seen,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rtrim(ltrim(Job_Number)) ORDER BY  ID) AS RowNum
      FROM Schedule  
      WHERE Assignees IN('9','16','22')
  )
  SELECT ID,Template_ID,Job_Number,Address,Other_Info,Assigned_By,Assignees, Active,seen FROM Dupes WHERE RowNum=1
```

Comment: I have tried the code and I am still getting the two rows with same Job_Number. I might have same Job_Number for different Template_ID in the table. I am updating my question now

Comment: try to use dense_rank() instead of row_number()

Comment: I am not sure why I still get the duplicate row. I have updated the code with picture

Comment: weird though, what's the data_type of your job_number?

Comment: I have used VARCHAR for Job_Number

Comment: try `partition by replace(Job_Number , ' ', '')` or  `cast(Job_Number as int)`

Comment: dense_rank() OVER(partition by replace(Job_Number , ' ', '') ORDER BY  ID) AS RowNum  like this? I am getting the same result

Comment: When I used cast, i got the error "The conversion of the varchar value '527468578965' overflowed an int column."

Comment: use bigint instead

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to bigint.
Getting this error

Comment: oh, seems there's some job_number that contains letters.

Comment: yeah, Job Number can have letters.

Comment: try run this query `select * from schedule where job_number = '57867564524'`

Comment: ahh! I am getting only one row then. Seems like white spaces

Comment: Let me try the above query now :)

Comment: try to use rtrim(ltrim(job_number))

Comment: ok sure,It's working now. I have used my query. Thanks a lot for the help.